# Bad SQL query Disk full (/tmp/#sql_58f_0); waiting for someone to free some space

Tags: sql-server, prestashop-1.6

I have Presta, and I like it but..
Now I get this strange error:

> Bad SQL query Disk full (/tmp/#sql_58f_0); waiting for someone to free
>   some space...

I googled a lot, but did not find any solution.

After I added EAN codes in my products field, my shop shows:

> No featured products at this time.

Prior to this all seemed to look fine.
I restored an old backup (from 2 months ago) and noticed that it already did had the same SQL error and after I added one EAN code, I see the same **no featured products**.

Not sure if the restore placed the shop back in 100 old condition, but with ean code's I have a total non working shop.
Even removing them dos not solve my problem.

I turned on debugging and received this as result:

```
{PrestaShopDatabaseException]

Disk full (/tmp/#sql_58f_0); waiting for someone to free some space...

SELECT
a.`id_category`, `name`, `description`, sa.`position` AS `position`, `active`
, sa.position position
FROM `ps_category` a 
LEFT JOIN `ps_category_lang` b ON (b.`id_category` = a.`id_category` AND b.`id_lang` = 1 AND b.`id_shop` = 1)
LEFT JOIN `ps_category_shop` sa ON (a.`id_category` = sa.`id_category` AND sa.id_shop = 1)  
WHERE 1   AND `id_parent` = 2 

ORDER BY sa.`position` ASC  LIMIT 0, 50
```

---

at line 791 in file classes/db/Db.php:

```
786.         if ($webservice_call && $errno) {
787.             $dbg = debug_backtrace();
788.             WebserviceRequest::getInstance()->setError(500, '[SQL Error] '.$this->getMsgError().'. From '.(isset($dbg[3]['class']) ? $dbg[3]['class'] : '').'->'.$dbg[3]['function'].'() Query was : '.$sql, 97);
789.         } elseif (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_ && $errno && !defined('PS_INSTALLATION_IN_PROGRESS')) {
790.             if ($sql) {

**791.                 throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError().'<br /><br /><pre>'.$sql.'</pre>');**

792.             }
793. 
794.             throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError());
795.         }
796.     }
```

---

```
DbCore->displayError - [line 425 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]

420.                 $this->result = $this->_query($sql);
421.             }
422.         }
423. 
424.         if (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_) {

**425.             $this->displayError($sql);**

426.         }
427. 
428.         return $this->result;
429.     }
430.
```

---

```
DbCore->query - [line 643 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]

Argument [0]
SELECT
a.`id_category`, `name`, `description`, sa.`position` AS `position`, `active`
, sa.position position
FROM `ps_category` a 
LEFT JOIN `ps_category_lang` b ON (b.`id_category` = a.`id_category` AND b.`id_lang` = 1 AND b.`id_shop` = 1)
LEFT JOIN `ps_category_shop` sa ON (a.`id_category` = sa.`id_category` AND sa.id_shop = 1)  
WHERE 1   AND `id_parent` = 2 

ORDER BY sa.`position` ASC  LIMIT 0, 50
```

---

```
DbCore->executeS - [line 3212 - classes/controller/AdminController.php] - [3 Arguments]

3207. '.($this->_tmpTableFilter ? ' * FROM (SELECT ' : '').$this->_listsql.$sql_from.$sql_join.' WHERE 1 '.$sql_where.
3208.                                 $sql_order_by.$sql_limit;
3209.                 $list_count = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `'._DB_PREFIX_.$this->table.'` '.$sql_from.$sql_join.' WHERE 1 '.$sql_where;
3210.             }
3211. 

**3212.             $this->_list = Db::getInstance()->executeS($this->_listsql, true, false);**

3213. 
3214.             if ($this->_list === false) {
3215.                 $this->_list_error = Db::getInstance()->getMsgError();
3216.                 break;
3217.             }
```

---

```
AdminControllerCore->getList - [line 253 - controllers/admin/AdminCategoriesController.php] - [6 Arguments]

248.         return parent::renderList();
249.     }
250. 
251.     public function getList($id_lang, $order_by = null, $order_way = null, $start = 0, $limit = null, $id_lang_shop = false)
252.     {

**253.         parent::getList($id_lang, $order_by, $order_way, $start, $limit, Context::getContext()->shop->id);**

254.         // Check each row to see if there are combinations and get the correct action in consequence
255. 
256.         $nb_items = count($this->_list);
257.         for ($i = 0; $i < $nb_items; $i++) {
258.             $item = &$this->_list[$i];
```

---

```
AdminCategoriesControllerCore->getList - [line 2333 - classes/controller/AdminController.php] - [1 Arguments]

Argument [0]
1
```

---

```
AdminControllerCore->renderList - [line 248 - controllers/admin/AdminCategoriesController.php]

243.             $this->tpl_list_vars['delete_category'] = true;
244.             $this->tpl_list_vars['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
245.             $this->tpl_list_vars['POST'] = $_POST;
246.         }
247. 

**248.         return parent::renderList();**

249.     }
250. 
251.     public function getList($id_lang, $order_by = null, $order_way = null, $start = 0, $limit = null, $id_lang_shop = false)
252.     {
253.         parent::getList($id_lang, $order_by, $order_way, $start, $limit, Context::getContext()->shop->id);
```

---

```
AdminCategoriesControllerCore->renderList - [line 2034 - classes/controller/AdminController.php]

2029.         } elseif ($this->display == 'details') {
2030.             $this->content .= $this->renderDetails();
2031.         } elseif (!$this->ajax) {
2032.             $this->content .= $this->renderModulesList();
2033.             $this->content .= $this->renderKpis();

**2034.             $this->content .= $this->renderList();**

2035.             $this->content .= $this->renderOptions();
2036. 
2037.             // if we have to display the required fields form
2038.             if ($this->required_database) {
2039.                 $this->content .= $this->displayRequiredFields();
```

---

```
AdminControllerCore->initContent - [line 199 - controllers/admin/AdminCategoriesController.php]

194.                 'url_delete' => htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),
195.                 'boxes' => $this->boxes,
196.             ));
197.         }
198. 

**199.         parent::initContent();**

200.     }
201. 
202.     public function setMedia()
203.     {
204.         parent::setMedia();
```

---

```
AdminCategoriesControllerCore->initContent - [line 189 - classes/controller/Controller.php]

184.             if (!$this->content_only && ($this->display_header || (isset($this->className) && $this->className))) {
185.                 $this->initHeader();
186.             }
187. 
188.             if ($this->viewAccess()) {

**189.                 $this->initContent();**

190.             } else {
191.                 $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Access denied.');
192.             }
193. 
194.             if (!$this->content_only && ($this->display_footer || (isset($this->className) && $this->className))) {
```

---

```
ControllerCore->run - [line 367 - classes/Dispatcher.php]

362.             if (isset($params_hook_action_dispatcher)) {
363.                 Hook::exec('actionDispatcher', $params_hook_action_dispatcher);
364.             }
365. 
366.             // Running controller

**367.             $controller->run();**

368.         } catch (PrestaShopException $e) {
369.             $e->displayMessage();
370.         }
371.     }
372.
```

---

```
DispatcherCore->dispatch - [line 58 - admin/index.php]

53. if (!isset($_REQUEST['controller']) && isset($_REQUEST['tab'])) {
54.     $_REQUEST['controller'] = strtolower($_REQUEST['tab']);
55. }
56. 
57. // Prepare and trigger admin dispatcher


**58. Dispatcher::getInstance()->dispatch();**
```

---

Google isn't much help.

Have you seen this before, and how can I (or someone else) fix this?

Thank you for feedback!

p.s. the domain is Giantjeans.com

Comment: I haven't seen your all the code. But just making a guess ... this might be a tempdb insufficient space issue ? try monitoring temp db ...

Comment: All this code, did you check if your disk is full?

Comment: Hi, I have 50GB of SSD, with only 2 GB in use.
It can be that the tmp is on a separate partition, who's only one GB.

I have no Idea on how to change form one partition to the large root partition.
I tried some, but it only killed my server...
Lucky I had a backup.

How can I clean a temp db folder?

Comment: Is it joining rows together in such a way that vast numbers of rows are being returned?   Estimate how many records it returns - what if you start with TOP 10 and see if it works, then up it until you get the full set - then top 1000, TOP 1000000 and so on - my guess is it makes such a big set of data that it blows the disk space

Comment: Hi Andrew,

Can you tell me how to do this?
I have no idea.
I'm quite sure the /tmp is a separate partition. 
And that is "only" one GB.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your web hosting the disk space (in this case the database size) is less or the SQL-server is having too many requests to the database at the same time.

Because of which Prestashop is not able to write the data. In order to fix the issues, you need to check the server error to know the exact reason.

It is recommended that you upgrade your server and get some more free space.

Comment: :-)

Yes, I am aware of this.
My question is HOW DO I DO THIS?

Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_directadmin-lv_root 48G 4.4G 44G 10% /
/dev/mapper/vg_directadmin-lv_tmp 1014M 1014M 20K 100% /tmp

So I am fully aware that my tmp is full.

How do I get it empty?
Reboot is not helping.

The SQL server has nothing to do. Database is 
Disk Usage 1.42 GB 
  Email Disk Usage 28.5 MB 
  Database Disk Usage 36.6 MB 

As you can see I have 44 GB space left on the root partition, and 20kb on the tmp partition.

How do I get this empty?

Comment: :-)

Live can be simple. 
On the whole internet I read that I need to leave the files alone in the tpm partition.

My solution was not to listen. And just delete all files in the tmp partition and reboot the server.
That solved my problem.
I now only have 33mb in use on the 1025mb partition :-)